# How to extract default_scope query and call it in a has_many relationship? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

It's my first question in stackoverflow because always i find whatever i need, but not this time. I'll explain my case...

I have this models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rents
end

class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  default_scope { where "end < ?", Time.now }
end
```

And their schemas:

```
  create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "brand"
    t.string   "model"
    t.string   "family"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "passengers"
    t.string   "trunk"
    t.string   "doors"
    t.string   "plate"
    t.string   "transmission"
  end
  create_table "rents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "car_id"
  end
```

I'm trying to find a way to get the same results, through scope's way, that i have if i type this in my controller:

```
def results
  @cars = Car.all
end
```

I get all the cars, and those rents which have a "end" value bigger than the param "Time.now", and those which doesn't have one rent.
My goal is to do this query something similar to this way, calling a scope:

```
def results
  @cars = Car.available_for_rent
end
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, a car is available when @car.rents.where("start > ?", Time.now).where("end < ?", Time.now) returns []?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lusketeer. It gives me a syntax error if i put it on a view or my controller. I'm trying to send all the cars and their rents which satisfy the query from the controller. The objective is how to call a named scope in the same way default_scope do it without being called.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I proposed in comment was wrong.

Since you want the cars that are available, we could go from the opposite side by looking up the cars that are currently in rental, therefore, we will need to look up the `rents` that are valid

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  scope :active, -> { where("rents.end > ?", Time.now).where("rents.start < ?", Time.now) }
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rents
  scope :unavailable, -> { joins(:rents).merge(Rent.active) }
  scope :available, -> { Car.where.not(id: Car.unavailable.pluck("cars.id") }
end
```

Another solution is to use LEFT JOIN

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rents
  scope :available, -> { Car.joins("LEFT JOIN (#{Rent.active.to_sql}) ON cars.id = rents.car_id").where("rents.car_id IS NULL") }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have more than i expected, because you showed me a correct way to think about the problem to solve it, beyond language or framework. You solutions is what i need. One more question: I see upper is more verbose than the other. Anyway, what would be better according to Rails or Ruby way?

Comment: you are welcome. I actually made another mistake in the LEFT JOIN query one, I forgot to filter the active rents. see the updated one. As for what would be better, personally, I prefer whichever runs the fastest, that's why I put the LEFT JOIN one since it's only one query, but I would keep the rest of them in the model as well for future reference, comment out the one you don't use, and use the one performs the best

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rents
  scope :available_for_rent, joins(:rents).where("rents.end < ?", Time.now)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @qubit. I tried that, but it throws me a "ArgumentError in StaticController#results", "The scope body needs to be callable". So, i wrapped it into a proc/lambda "  
scope :available_for_rent, ->(time) {
    joins(:rents).where('rents.end < ?', time)
}
, and the results are good, but it duplicates my first car. Any idea?

Comment: Np, glad it helped you to make it work. Can you check for the actual sql queries in the log file while you are calling the scope?

Comment: Thanks for your time, @qubit. I found the solution i needed. Thanks again.